# How to check if UiInstance is running?

Tags: google-apps-script

How to check if a UiInstance is already running? I need to know so that I know whether to use UiApp.getActiveApplication() or UiApp.createApplication(); The issue is that the functions may not be called in a particular order.

Comment: Have you tried calling getActiveApplication to see what it returns when theres none?

Answer (score 0):

No offense but this question doesn't make a lot of sense to me...  There can be only one UiApp instance and in a standalone app it must start with a `doGet()` so I wonder how you could start an app without starting by the app creation ?
Once you have created this instance it lives as long as you close your browser window of you hide all the possible source of user actions (for example hiding all the widgets or disabling all the buttons) and everything that happens in between is either the result of a handler call or a direct function call in the script, all of which are necessarily subsequent and therefor using `getActiveApplication()`.

If I missed something (which is entirely possible of course) please explain.

---

**Edit :** following your comment :

In case you use UiApp embedded in a document the situation is a bit different but not so much : 
2 different cases :

1. Dialogs :each time you create a new one it will appear "over" the existing one but won't be "aware" of it, i.e none of the first UI values will be available to the next one. So it's a better idea to close each one before creating a new one (`app.close();return app;`) otherwise you'll have to manually close each "layer" successively since I guess it wouldn't be a good idea to keep the dialog on the screen all along :-)
   Data passing from one instance to the other must be handled using some kind of storage.
2. Sidebar : what I'd suggest is to create a starting UI in the sidebar that creates the Ui (showing a welcome message or a menu for example) and let all the other function get this Ui Instance using `getActiveApplication()` , that will avoid the UI "flashing" while it's been redrawn and allow you to play with all the values all along.

In both case the choice is really yours but the practice I suggest works better and gives you full control on what happens.

Comment: Oh sorry, not a stand alone app. It's in a container bound one within a Google Doc